# Home insurer asked for proof that my windows can withstand 110 MPH winds

Tags: home-insurance

I'm renewing the policy.  Got a good quote from Metlife, gave him all the info, even entered CC#.  Then he suddenly says his "underwriter" wants something on letterhead stating that my home can handle the 110 mph winds.  Quote: "Just get your contractor buddy write it for you."  Since I don't have any contractor buddies -- can anyone explain what this is about?  I'm in NYC.

Comment: [According to this article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-us-canada-14677021/testing-a-hurricane-how-powerful-are-110mph-winds) hurricane Irene from 2011 was a category 2 storm with winds hitting 110 mph. I've never experienced such winds, but I think I'd be wanting an insurance company to be paying out if one hit, not – as I suspect this request might imply – responding "_sorry, you said your home was strong enough so we're not paying_",

Comment: Well OK, this house survived both Irene and Sandy without a single claim.  Isn't that enough?

Comment: This sounds absurd. Even if your windows could handle 110-mph winds, they can't handle solid debris (tree branches, street signs) flying at 110 mph.

Comment: Summary: You get the insurance elsewhere, unless that requirement magically disappears.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured.  I posted to make sure that I'm not out-of-date with modern trends.  If any agents chime in -- would be nice.